# One-to-many matching of propensity scores and average treatment effect on the treated

Tags: propensity-scores, treatment-effect

I've been working on a propensity score matching project, but having no stats classes under my belt I'm struggling to calculate the so called "average treatment effect on the treated" (ATT) so that it will be statistically valid. It seems straight-forward enough when looking at the following formula:

$ATT  = E[y1 - y0 | p(x)] = E[y | t = 1,p(x)] - E[y | t = 0, p(x)]$

That is, the average treatment effect on the treated is equal to the expected value ($E$ = average in this case) of the difference between the outcome variable (for example, $y$ = income) for treated and untreated individuals (where, for example, treated individuals ($t=1$) received some sort of training and untreated individuals ($t=0$) did not), conditional on their propensity scores, $p(x)$ (i.e. when their propensity scores match "well enough"). With one-to-one matching of treated and control individuals using nearest neighbour or exact matching, calculating ATT manually in a spreadsheet is fine, but when matching more than one control to each treated individual things seem to get a little tricky. As such, I'm hoping someone may be able to help me figure out what the generally accepted methods for calculating ATT are when dealing with one-to-many matching between treated and control individuals.

Comment: Is your formula measuring the average treatment effect rather than the average treatment effect for the treated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All matching estimators for the treatment on the treated effect can be written in the form

$$ \frac{1}{n_T} \sum_{i \in \{d_i=1\}} \left[ y_{1i} - \sum_{j \in \{d_j = 0 \}} w_{ij} \cdot y_{0j} \right] ,$$

where $w_{ij}$ is the weight placed on the $j$th untreated observation as a counterfactual for the $i$th treated observation, and $n_T$ is the number of treated persons. The weights satisfy $\sum_j w_{ij}=1$ for all $i$.

Effectively, from each treated observation $i$, you subtract a weighted average of the control observations. Then you take the average of these differences. These weights are specific to observation $i$. Different matching estimators differ in how they construct the weights.

For example, *nearest neighbor matching* sets the weight to 1 for the single untreated observations closest to $i$ in terms of the propensity score and to 0 for all others. k-NN uses $k$ closest neighbors instead.

*Interval matching* consists of dividing the range of propensity scores into a fixed number of intervals (which need not be of equal length). An interval-specific estimate is obtained by taking the difference between the mean outcomes of the treated and untreated units in each interval.

*Radius/caliper matching* takes the mean of the outcomes for untreated units within a fixed radius of each treated unit as the estimated expected counterfactual. You pick the radius.

*Kernel matching* uses weights that decline with the PS distance. You can think about kernel matching as running a weighted regression for each treated observation using the comparison group data and the regression includes only an intercept term. Here you have to pick the kernel and the bandwidth. Larger bandwidth means further observations will have larger weights.

*Local linear matching* is very similar, but also included a linear term in PS. Some people will also include higher order polynomial terms.

Finally, you have *inverse probability weighting*. The basic idea is that you can figure out the expected untreated outcome (in either the treated population or the full population) by reweighting the observed values using the treatment probabilities.

There are some guidelines about how to pick a method [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25402/7071).

There is a list of software and packages that can do matching [here](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~estuart/propensityscoresoftware.html). Stata also now has native PSM estimators. In my experience, replicating the output by hand is often very hard once you go past the simplest estimators. However, you can also find examples with output for all of these online, so even if you don't have the software, they will give you a useful benchmark since you can usually track down the data.

Comment: Having completed a propensity score analysis, with good match balance between treated and control units, is there anything further that is needed in order to say whether the results are statistically significant? Or is it enough to have good covariate balance?

Comment: @user7388 You will need standard errors. You will want to make sure the distributions of PS for T and C have substantial overlap. Finally, balancing does not help with statistical significance (see section 3.4 in the [Caliendo & Sabine 2008 JES paper](https://faculty.unlv.edu/nasser/ECO%20772,%20Econometrics%20II/Reading%20List%20Articles/Caliendo%20and%20Sabine%20-%20Some%20Practical%20Guidance%20for%20the%20Implementation%20of%20Propensity%20Score%20Matching.pdf). Finally, I also like to show results from false palcebo tests (repeat the analysis before the effect takes place and ATT=0).

Comment: If you estimate an effect where you know there should be none, PSM will not work because you have selection into treatment on unobservables variables that PSM cannot help with.

Comment: When you say that I will need standard errors, do you think you could explain how I would implement that a little further, as having no stats background makes such things rather confusing :) Also, when you mention that the PS distributions for T and C have substantial overlap, is this the same as having good covariate balance or is it something more nuanced?

Comment: @user7388 Standard error will be reported by any of the stats packages linked above. Don't use Excel. If it is large relative to your estimate of ATET, you cannot rule out that the effect is zero with the data you have. Overlap means that for treated observations with PS near some value x you have some untreated observations with PS near x, so you can make comparisons that is apples to apples. Balancing is about getting the model of propensity for treatment correct. Honestly, PSM is pretty advanced stuff to be doing without statistical training. You're jumping in the deep end of the pool.

Comment: I see that the "Matching" package I use in R gives a standard error value underneath the ATT estimate of 0.559 so it looks like I thankfully won't have to calculate it myself. What exactly would the value of 0.559 represent? If I have an ATT estimate of 0.238 and a standard error or 0.559, would this mean that I could get extreme values of `0.238 + 0.559 = 0.797` or `0.238 - 0.559 = -0.321` for the ATT estimate?

Comment: @user7388 This means that your data is consistent with the effect being zero (assuming everything else about the analysis is correct). Given your results, the p-value on the null hypothesis of no effect is approximately 0.67, so you cannot reject it. I would recommend the Andrew Vicker's book What is a p-Value Anyway? if you need help understanding hypothesis testing. Here's a [nice passage](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72583/7071) from it that I have found helpful in explaing the main ideas in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Edit -
Please find below comprehensive list of options -
http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~estuart/propensityscoresoftware.html

More detailed link about Matching
http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/papers/MatchingJSS.pdf

---

There is an R package which will for this-
http://pareonline.net/pdf/v19n18.pdf
This should take care of any computational issue you are Facing with spreadsheet.

For general practices please refer to following links for general practices
http://ftp.iza.org/dp1588.pdf
http://www.iadb.org/wmsfiles/products/publications/documents/35320229.pdf

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nishad, the pareonline link only goes so far as matching and does not calculate ATT. Since creating this thread I've started using the "Matching" package in R, but would like to be able to test its results against other similar matching packages to make sure I'm doing what I think I'm doing. I tried using the "Match" package for R, but their explanation of calculating ATT was confusing. Do you know of any other packages or programs (preferably free) that I could use to check if my "Matching" package ATT results are correct?

Comment: There are these alternatives that I could find