# Is propensity score matching out of favor?

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, matching

I came across this [post](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1512860-which-order-is-correct-did-than-psm-or-psm-than-did), which was largely nonsensical, but a respondent suggested the original poster follow up with two articles:

Ho, D. E., Imai, K., King, G., & Stuart, E. A. (2007). Matching as nonparametric preprocessing for reducing model dependence in parametric causal inference. Political analysis, 15(3), 199-236.

King, G., & Nielsen, R. (2016). Why propensity scores should not be used for matching. Political Analysis, 1-20.

The first article argues for using PSM, the second basically says it's not good practice.

I have a dataset where I have individuals who moved with assistance from Program A, and individuals who moved without any assistance, and I want to compare outcomes. Has PSM fallen out of favor, statistically, for such analyses?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Propensity score matching - What is the problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481110/propensity-score-matching-what-is-the-problem) The answer from @Noah on that page is a superb overview of the tradeoffs involved in propensity score matching (PSM), written by an expert in the field.

Comment: That is a great response, thank you. Follow up question: where should a person start in finding the right methods for comparing two groups, one of which received a non-random treatment - although maybe this is too broad to ask? I'm just not really sure how to approach figuring out what to do with the data at this point.

Comment: [Matthay et al. (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ssmph.2019.100526) might be a nice place to start. I also suggest my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/544958/116195). As far as choosing the best method, you need to work with someone who has a PhD in statistical methodology for causal inference to determine which statistical method best suites your data, question, and assumptions best. If you're problem is interesting, I'm sure a statistician would love to collaborate.