# Choosing variables for propensity score matching

Tags: survival, propensity-scores, matching

I'm working on a project dealing with transplants and comparing outcomes of first time (primary) transplants with re-transplants. I'm trying to decide which set of variables to include for propensity score matching.

For example, for the category of age, would it be better to match based on age at the time of the first transplant for both cohorts or for the age at the time of the first transplant for the primary transplant group and age at the time of retransplant for the retransplant group?

Comment: I don't know which are your control and treatment group, but typically the answer would be whichever variables your theory and the literature suggest would satisfy the ignorability and positivity assumptions, and check balance before the matching. Additionally, why do you have the survival tag?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use propensity score _matching_? That runs a risk of throwing away useful data and leads to problems that other ways to control for confounding can help to avoid. With other adjustment techniques, you could in principle control for all of those factors and not have to choose which to match. Please read [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/481110/28500) for a superb, expert explanation.